# Apply filter on all elements except one

Tags: jquery, css

I try to apply opacity on the body except one element

```
$('body').css('opacity', '0.45');
$('body').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=45)');
```

except one element like something like this

```
$('#fadeForSearch').not('body').css('opacity', '0.45');
$('#fadeForSearch').not('body').css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=45)');
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: if you apply on body you will apply on all its content thus to all the elements

Comment: Opacity is herited from parent element [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). Maybe you could try to use `background-color:rgba(200,200,200,.45)`

Comment: Opacity is not really inherit, but much worse. There's no overriding in the way you would any inherited property. When you set the parent to .45, that's the max opacity any children can get. Their "opacity 1"(default) becomes something like "use 100% of the max opacity allowed by the parent", which still lets them at .45 from a visual point of view. If you have the parent set to .5 then apply opacity .5 on a children, the children gets a .25 visual opacity. Hope that helps you understand how it works.. You cannot simply set the opacity of the body then have an element override it.

Comment: @Facundo Corradini Thanks for this explain

Comment: @FacundoCorradini this is true. haven't tested it but it might work if the child element is absolutely positioned. but im not sure whether it fits to your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you're trying to do is actually fading everything but the search input when you click on it, you can get away by displaying a semi-transparent, fixed positioned layer with 100% height and 100% show up when your input is focused. Input must have a higher z-index (+ position relative/absolute for the z-index to work) so it stays above the overlay.

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
  background-color: steelblue;
}

.overlay{
  width: 100%; height:100%;
  position:fixed; top:0; left:0;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display:none;
}

input{
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}

input:focus ~ .overlay{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</body>
```